# An obsevation of Monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the Monotone Convergence Theorem may not hold for decreasing sequences of functions.

Suppose $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative decreasing functions converging to $f$ pointwise. I know that if $f_{1}$ is finite,we can construct the sequence say $\left\{f_{1}-f_{n}\right\}$ which is increasing to prove that MCT still hold for decreasing sequence. So the only way in which the MCT is not valid is when $f_{1}$ is not finite. I don't know how to construct such sequence.

Comment: There is a difference between a sequence of decreasing functions and a decreasing sequence of functions, but you seem to have used them interchangably.

Comment: @Andrews Yes,yo're right.Throughout the context above,what I really mean is the decreasing sequence of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Define the sequence $\{f_n\}$ on $[0,\infty)$ by letting $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, and
$$ f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx}\qquad (x\in(0,\infty). $$
Then $f_n$ is monotonically decreasing, and converges pointwise to $0$ on $[0,\infty)$.  However,
$$\int_{[0,\infty)}f_n\ dm=\infty,$$
while
$$\int_{[0,\infty)}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\ dm=0. $$

Answer (score 0):

Put $f_n=\infty\chi_{(0,1/n)}$